# ¿Se puede añadir algún elemento en un arreglo dentro de otro arreglo python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un arreglo y quiero añadirle un valor al arreglo que esta dentro de este pero no se si es posible he intentado con insert pero no me funciona de antemano gracias

```
inventario=[0,[1,2]]
inventario.insert([1][1],6)
print(inventario)
```

Comment: Que es exactamente lo que esperas que ocurra en la segunda linea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La respuesta es si, las listas son MUTABLES**.

**Interpreto** que lo que quieres hacer es pasar de esto [0, [1, 2]] a esto [0, [1, 6, 2]].

El método insert de una lista acepta como primer parámetro un int (número entero), que es la posición (index) de la lista donde quieres insertar tu objeto.

Cuando pasas [1][1] como primer parámetro, el método **insert no interpreta [1][1] como el lugar de tu lista bidimensional donde quieres insertar tu objeto** sino el lugar donde debe ir a mirar para encontrar el indice que debe utilizar para insertar el objeto en tu lista (**te confundes con una asignacon directa como inventario[1][1] = 1**, que no sería lo mismo que insert).

Como [1][1] es un acceso a una lista vacia, te manda un mensaje de index out of range.

Para conseguir lo que quieres yo haría:

```
inventario=[0,[1,2]]
#inventario[1] acceso a segundo (index=1) objeto de inventario 
#.insert(1,6) inserta en la segunda posición (index = 1) de la lista [1,2] el int 6  
inventario[1].insert(1,6) 
print(inventario)
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en la función que estas utilizando. Para añadir un elemento a una lista, interpretando "añadir" como insertar un nuevo elemento al final de una lista, tienes el método "append". Este es un método propio de la clase "list" que te permite introducir un elemento como último elemento de la lista.

Ejemplo:

```
inventario=[0,[1,2]]
# Como quieres añadir el elemento en la lista ubicada en la segunda posicion (indice=1) es necesario apuntar sobre este elemento: "inventario[1]"
inventario[1].append(6)
print(inventario)
# Cuyo output es: [0,[1,2,6]]
```